# Hibernate.initialize after session close does not work

Tags: hibernate

This can be duplicate of some other thread. But I am trying to run the console application to understand hibernate initialize method. I wrote below program but it does not work for me.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Emp emp2 = (Emp)session2.load(Emp.class, 1);
    emp2.getEmail();
    session2.close();
    unproxy(emp2);
    System.out.println(emp2.getAddress());

}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T unproxy(T entity) {
    if (entity == null) {
        return null;
    }
    System.out.println(entity.getClass());
    if (entity instanceof HibernateProxy) {
        Hibernate.initialize(entity);
        entity = (T) ((HibernateProxy) entity).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getImplementation();
    }
    return entity;
}
```

}

I am getting below exception.

```
SEVERE: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sample.hibernate.Emp.address, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.sample.hibernate.Emp.address, no session or session was closed
```

So does it mean that I can not load lazy objects using initialize method after session close? If not what are the other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So does it mean that I can not load lazy objects using initialize
>   method after session close? If not what are the other ways?

That's exactly what it means. Lazy loading means loading objects only when you need them, but this requires that you still have a live connection (within a session and possibly within a transaction) to the database.

After you've closed the `Session`, it is impossible to initialize the proxies created for lazy loading.

Comment: Just for curiosity, What is the use of initialize method? We can even get the lazy loadable association even without initialize method within session.

Comment: @javafan Depends on the situation. It's possible that you initially want to lazy load, but reconsider after checking some condition. `Hibernate.initialize()` allows you to do that.